# How to write unit test for an extension method that contains Assembly class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have an extension method as follows:

```cs
public static partial class Extensions
{
    public static T GetAttribute<T>(this Assembly @this) where T : Attribute
    {
        object[] configAttributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(@this, typeof (T), false);

        if (configAttributes != null && configAttributes.Length > 0)
        {
            return (T) configAttributes[0];
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

My question is how should I write a unit test for this scenario?
Can anyone guide me?

Comment: `@this` as a parameter name is not a good idea. The `@` is a hint that you're doing something weird: `this` is a keyword. Just name it `thisAssembly` or such. You don't have to pay per character...

Comment: @JHBonarius I disagree. Actually, for extension methods, I do think `@this` is an _excellent_ idea, as it describes that it works on another object as if it would be a method within the object itself.

Comment: @UweKeim On hindsight I now think that `thisAssembly` also isn't right. I would just use `assembly`, as an extention method is just is a normal static method (function) that can be called another way: it's not a 'member' method, as you don't have access to the privates. So using the `this` object (pointer/reference) seems out of place. Anyhow, if you want something like that, I would use the name `self` , as that is commonly used for a reference to the instance of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Assembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly) is just a class. A rather abstract one actually. You can derive from it.

```cs
class MockAssembly : Assembly {}
```

However, this is not enough, as [`Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly, Type, Boolean)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attribute.getcustomattributes#system-attribute-getcustomattributes(system-reflection-assembly-system-type-system-boolean)) will make a call to [`Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type, bool)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getcustomattributes), which is a virtual method, so you need to override that. For example:

```cs
class MockAttribute : Attribute { }

class MockAssembly : Assembly
{
    public override object[] GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, bool inherit)
    {
        return new[] { new MockAttribute() };
    }
}
```

You can now test:

```cs
var assembly = new MockAssembly();
var att = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(assembly, typeof(MockAttribute), false);
Console.WriteLine(att.Length);
```

will return: 1